# user does not change the registry first time(Shell Value) but do change in second attempt on remote

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I have made an window application ,that application have change in registry shell value.when AD admin user login first time with full permission,application prompts first time and user authenticate with MFA options then for the first time user does not able to change the registry shell's value,but when he changes in second time he does successfully change the registry.All the scenario is going on RDP only.

we have already given the full control to change the registry permission to admin user.

```
RegistryKey localKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry64);
localKey = localKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", true);
localKey.SetValue("Shell", "explorer.exe");

RegistryKey localKey1 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry32);
localKey1 = localKey1.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", true);
localKey1.SetValue("Shell", "explorer.exe");

Thread.Sleep(2000);
Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\system32\userinit.exe");
```